# How to move down from the current directory using PHP getcwd()

Tags: php

I have a current working directory like this

> ../home/username/workspace/php

But I want to go to

> ../home/username/workspace/uploads

Using [getcwd()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_getcwd.asp) will return the current working directory but I want to go to the uploads folder, and `fopen(getcwd() . '../uploads/' . 'image.png', 'r');` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

getcwd() returns the current working directory without trailing backslash and the path will be like this:
`/home/username/workspace/php../uploads/image.png`

Does this work?
`fopen(getcwd() . '/../uploads/' . 'image.png', 'r');`